# php while loop confusion

Tags: php, arrays, object, while-loop

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, user_name, display_name FROM uc_users");

    while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {

       // do something

    }
```

I cannot understand how PHP will evaluate the condition in the While loop.

`$results` is an object. `$row` is an array. What is `while($row = $results->fetch_array())`? And when will it evaluate to TRUE, and when to FALSE ?

Comment: `$row` is not an array, but the current element of the array which is assigned by `$results->fetch_array()`, once `$row` becomes empty it will evaluate to `false` hence moving out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the while evaluates the condition, it does the following:

- Gather the result of fetch_array
- Put it in $row
- At this point, it will check the content of $row and see if it's null not
- If it's null, it'll quit the loop, if not, it'll continue indefinitely

Comment: What is surprising is that if you check the PHP Manual, there's nothing about how a While loop condition evaluates arrays.

Comment: An array is always "true" in a condition, "false" is returned when the value is null or 0 or empty, generally speaking.